# Can YOU guess this Riley Riddle?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, knowledge

My Prefix returns us to the dark ages.

My Infix belongs to someone.

My Suffix has annoyed me since birth.

Hint 1:

> Prefix is an Acronym.

Hint 2:

> Infix is a Verb in the 3rd person present tense.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it is

> Emphasis

My Prefix returns us to the dark ages.

> [EMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse) can harm electronic devices

My Infix belongs to someone.

> Has

My Suffix has annoyed me since birth.

> Your "Sis" or sister

Bonus:

> There is emphasis in the title of the question "Can YOU guess this Riley Riddle?"

Comment: That's it! Well done :)

Answer (score 8):

Could it possibly be

> ADHERENT?

My Prefix returns us to the dark ages.

> The acronym AD, perhaps?

My Infix belongs to someone.

> It belongs to HER.

My Suffix has annoyed me since birth.

> Nobody likes paying RENT!

Comment: (rot13)fb, lbh unir orra cnlvat erag fvapr ovegu gura? :Q

Comment: @Cashbee wouldn’t that _really_ annoy you if you did though? Although on a more serious note, technically by doing chores, etc...? I couldn’t find a suffix that fit the prefix and infix haha.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer:**

Prefix-

> Ether , since there is a knowledge tag, i am going to guess it to be the reality stone from marvel movies, in thor2 it was about to be used to bring back the dark ages.

Infix-

> Her, belongs to her.

Suffix-

> not sure yet.

Comment: I'm afraid neither of those are correct, but the knowledge tag does apply to the Prefix. It's a real world thing, not fictional, but good try! :)

Answer (score 2):

It is:

> **Stonyhearted**

Prefix:

> **Stony**: *Covered with or full of small pieces of rock*
>  Brings us to stone age, somewhat dark age in human history

Infix:

> **Heart**: Belongs to someone

Suffix:

> **Ted**: *turn over and spread out (grass, hay, or straw) to dry or for bedding*.
>  Improper tedding can be annoying.

Comment: Sorry but nowhere near :)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial**

**Prefix**

> **F**all **O**f **R**ome (for) or **F**all **O**f **R**oman **E**mpire (fore)

Comment: Good idea but that's not it :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> FORMYL ?

My Prefix returns us to the dark ages.

> FOR - Fall Of Rome, credits to @jc1850

My Infix belongs to someone.

> MY - it belongs to meeeeeeee

My Suffix has annoyed me since birth.

> L - Yes I hate the letter L too, OP. :)

Comment: Nope sorry, good try though :)